# JIRA Azure DevOps iteration not showing work item in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, jira

I am using Azure DevOps Git Repo and Jira Cloud. There are 2 issues not if these are expected behavior when using Azure DevOps Git

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220515/azure-pipelines-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview

1) After doing the build when it see the build result I do not see the JIRA ID under work item even though in the commit message I have included the JIRA ID, but the JIRA ID does show up in the Release work item

2) On the JIRA side when I go to the JIRA ticket in the “Releases” section I see “Undefined Environment”. On clicking on it I do see the release to which stages it has been deployed to. In the release configuration I have mapped each Stage to Deployment Type.
[image]

[image]

**Azure DevOps Settings**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very thanks for your detailed info shared.

For your first issue:

> After doing the build when it see the build result I do not see the
>   JIRA ID under work item even though in the commit message I have
>   included the JIRA ID

This is a expected action. Until now, we haven't support display the Jira issue info in build result. The method we provided is viewing it in the work items tab of release pipeline. You can refer to this official doc to get this: [Get Jira in VSTS working](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-jira/blob/master/tutorial.md#get-it-working).

> On the JIRA side when I go to the JIRA ticket in the “Releases”
>   section I see “Undefined Environment”.

Unfortunately, until now, if you map your Stage into the Deployment type, it will not display these release record under the Deployment panel in Jira.

Please check this doc published from Jira: [Viewing the development information for an issue](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/viewing-the-development-information-for-an-issue-777002795.html). Until now, the Deplopyment Panel only support the source which come from below servers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information. Will there be enhancement to have JIRA id showup under work items for Builds ? Also is there any enhancement for JIRA to support AzureDevOps?

Comment: @kumar, We are in the process of tight development and integration with Jira. We would take it as roadmap if this is a high priority feature for most users. In addition, do you mean that is there any other plugin or extension exists now, which could  enhancement for JIRA to support AzureDevOps? Is this, sorry to say, until now, I haven't found such tool.

Comment: Looking forward for tight integration with JIRA. Will the integration be happening through the same plugin. Also would it be possible to share the road map and timelines?

Comment: @kumar Of course yes, it will be integrated in the same plugin. Would expand feature based on it. I have checked our recently sprints, sorry because of other demand which has higher priority. https://dev.azure.com/mseng/azuredevopsroadmap/_workitems/recentlyupdated Here is our Roadmap, you could track it. For timeline, I can not give you the sure answer because this need be determined by the actual meeting and argument.